# Method Not Allowed (submit form with jQuery in Django)

Tags: python, jquery, django

I want to submit my "contact us" form on my Django website with jQuery.

I'm working on development server.

The error I receive in the browser and Django shell is:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /
Method Not Allowed: /
[01/May/2023 17:08:34] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

This is my view:

```py
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'

def submit_contact_form(request):
    if is_ajax(request=request):
        sender_name = request.POST.get('sender_name')
        sender_email = request.POST.get('sender_email')
        message_subject = request.POST.get('message_subject')
        message_body = request.POST.get('message_body')
        remote_addr = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        remote_host = request.META.get('REMOTE_HOST')

        context = {
            'from': sender_name,
            'email': sender_email,
            'subject': message_subject,
            'message': message_body,
            'IP': remote_addr,
            'HOST': remote_host,
        }

        html_message = render_to_string('homepage/submit.contact.form.html', context)

        send_mail(
            f'Contact Form Submission: {message_subject}',
            f'{message_body}',
            'myemail@mydomain.com',
            ['myemail@mydomain.com', ],
            html_message=html_message,
        )
        return JsonResponse({}, status=200)
    else:
        return redirect('homepage:index')
```

This is the jQuery code stored in a `js` file:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#sent-message').css("display", "none");
    $('#loading').css("display", "block");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/submit-contact-form/",
        data: {
            sender_name: $('#name').val(),
            sender_email: $('#email').val(),
            message_subject: $('#subject').val(),
            message_body: $('#message').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken,
            datatype: "json",
        },

        success: function(){
            $('#loading').css("display", "none");
            $('#sent-message').css("display", "block");
            $('#contact-form').trigger('reset');
            $('#sent-message').delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
        },

        error: function(){
            $('#loading').css("display", "none");
            $('#error-message').css("display", "block");
            $('#error-message').append("An error has occured. Please try again later.");
        }
    });
});
```

As far as I can tell, this should work. I'm sure I'm making some stupid mistakes somewhere.

Please assist.

Answer (score -1):

You have missed

> if request.method == "post"

which allows django to process post requests.

This should fix your problem

```
def submit_contact_form(request):
    if request.method == "post" and is_ajax(request=request):
        sender_name = request.POST.get('sender_name')
        sender_email = request.POST.get('sender_email')
        message_subject = request.POST.get('message_subject')
        message_body = request.POST.get('message_body')
        remote_addr = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        remote_host = request.META.get('REMOTE_HOST')

        context = {
            'from': sender_name,
            'email': sender_email,
            'subject': message_subject,
            'message': message_body,
            'IP': remote_addr,
            'HOST': remote_host,
        }

        html_message = render_to_string('homepage/submit.contact.form.html', context)

        send_mail(
            f'Contact Form Submission: {message_subject}',
            f'{message_body}',
            'myemail@mydomain.com',
            ['myemail@mydomain.com', ],
            html_message=html_message,
        )
        return JsonResponse({}, status=200)
    else:
        return redirect('homepage:index')
```

Comment: I have already tried that and didn't work. Same error.

Comment: If Django cannot process POST requests it should go to the ```else``` statement and redirect to the homepage, which is what happens when I browse to ```http://localhost:8000/submit-contact-form```. Here the issue is that Django does not allow POST requests to that view.

Comment: is it possible that your request is calling the root url that is <your_domain>/, which is why you are getting 405 method not allowed because the root url does not take post request.

Comment: That's what I see in the error message, but I've specified the URL in the body of AJAX function to ```/submit-contact-form/```. This is what I don't understand.

Comment: I believe your script is not running, could you try console.log? I think you have not put "action" attribute in your form and your js function is not being called, therefore it will post to the current url i.e. your root url so you are getting 405. Please check if the form id matches. This is all I can think of currently.